# Convert PHP string to custom formatted array for function

Tags: php, arrays

I need help converting a PHP string into an array that is formatted to work within a PHP function. I have a string like this:

```
$string = '11111, 22222, 33333';
```

I need this string to explode into an array that looks like this:

```
array("11111"=>"11111","22222"=>"22222","33333"=>"33333")';
```

The function looks like this:

```
function callback_numbers() {   
  $numbers = array( 
       "11111"=>"11111",
       "22222"=>"22222", 
       "33333"=>"33333", 
  );        
  return $numbers;         
}
```

I can't get the array to appear correctly when inside the function so that the array is returned correctly and the function works. When I `print_t $numbers` it looks ok but it won't work when I `return $numbers`.

Comment: You don't need `function` for this unless you will be using it `every` time you process the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Yoy can split using `,` but after you need to trim as there might be spaces between your numbers

```
$string = '11111, 22222, 33333';
$numbers = explode(',', $string );
$result = [];

foreach ($numbers as $item) {
  $item = trim( $item );
  $result [ $item ] = $item;
}

var_dump($result);
```